How can I properly terminate an unused opamp?
I was going through this article from TI regarding unused op-amp termination. It says that when an op-amp is single supply you can use the termination given in this figure:
Figure 1:

When it is using a split supply rail (assuming it is symmetric) you can use the termination given in this figure:
Figure 2

My question is regarding split supply operation.
When the split supplies are not equal, which termination scheme is good?  Take, for example,  V+ be 15V and V- be -13.5V.
I believe in this case the termination scheme given in Figure 1 is good because it will reduce the current draw by the op-amp from the supply.

The first case always draws current through the bias resistors, even if they are at the MΩ level.
The second case will be just as good with equal or unequal supplies, as long as the input is within the common mode range of the opamp, which will usually be the case.
Note that for some single supply opamps, the input common mode range includes the negative supply, it is possible to just connect the +ve input to there. However, CL has pointed out that for the wrong sense of input offset voltage, the output cannot get below the negative rail, and the driver stages may saturate and draw more current. So that's not a good idea.
Caveat - there may be some opamps that have a supply current that varies as a function of output voltage (there are some low voltage R2R types that have an offset voltage as a function of input voltage!) for which the minimum current is achieved at some particular input/output voltage.

By current draw I mean the current drawn by opamp from the supply.That will be less in figure one

@Confused Why do you believe the amplifier draws different quiescent current in the two cases? Does the datasheet for your particular amplifier specify that? Have you made any measurements? The output current is equal to the input bias current in both cases.

op amp's output will be railed low, causing the op amp to consume more supply current.

When you connect the input to the negative supply, and the offset voltage is right (wrong), then the output tries to go below the supply, and the output stage saturates and increases the supply current.

@Confused I've responded to CL's comment by correcting my answer. In both cases you have illustrated, the op-amp's output follows the input voltage. Neither is 'railed low'. I do not understand why you think they will draw different quiescent currents, do you have measurements or datasheet support?

@Neil_UK  The linked TI app note states that in single supply if you tie the non-inverting input to ground it will saturate the follower and can "potentially" cause more supply current.  My guess is this heavily depends on the internal construction of each opamp.  To test this, LTspice has educational examples for the LM741 and LM308 which are transistor level internal schematics that I created subcircuit models from.  I actually got higher quiescent current when the opamps were not saturated.  I don't know how this applies to modern opamps, however.


When the split supplies are not equal,Let V+ be 15V and V- be -13.5V. In this case which termination scheme is good ?.

Any termination scheme that respects the common mode range of the op-amp, or its implementation characteristics (e.g. LM358's internal schematic), is OK.

I believe in this case the termination scheme given in Figure1 is good because it will reduce the current draw by the opamp from the supply

What it will do - or won't do - depends on the op-amp type and has to be actually measured by yourself. No need to guess here. Test!

"depends on the op-amp type" - True.  "has to be actually measured by yourself" -- Not recommended.  It's better where possible to rely on the characteristics published by the manufacturer, since they consider manufacturing tolerances, different operating conditions such as temperature, and so on.  An end user would need an enormous amount of testing (and expense) to have information as good as what's published.

In both your circuits the opamp isn’t driving a load so no output current will flow so there is no difference in current draw of the opamp.
For the split supply case it’s a good idea to keep the inputs somewhere between the rails so figure 1 will accomplish that. Keeping those resistors large will make current draw through them negligible.
You can likely avoid the resistors entirely by connecting ‘+’ input to another net nearby that stays between the rails, say, the ‘+’ input of the other opamp in the package.
